# How to set up a local aosp mirror for use in different roms with source on git?

Tags: git, github, android-manifest, android-source

I'm interested in building a rom who's source is available on github.
To minimize downloads I wanted to mirror the AOSP repository on my local devbox. I used the example given by Google:

```
$ mkdir -p /usr/local/aosp/mirror
$ cd /usr/local/aosp/mirror
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/mirror/manifest --mirror
$ repo sync
```

After that I changed to my "android" map and did a repo init I did edit the `default.xml`, changed the path to fetch AOSP in my local path, without `https`.
When I do a repo sync command, It fails with errors referring to git, are you sure it is a git repository, have the right path etc. 
**Is there somewhere a tutorial I could follow what would show the steps in doing this correctly?**

M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working on source development things get little bit tricky, the `repo sync` is not a git command (it's basically a git of gits repository) and it's like this due to the large size of the AOSP.

For the exact same purpose of creating local server for the AOSP google developed free open source remote version control system name **Gerrit**.
Gerrit is like a local GitHub for your AOSP and it's also supports the Git framework.
[Here](https://nativeguru.wordpress.com/2015/05/22/how-to-set-local-aosp-gerrit-server-part-1/) is a great guide that will explain who to create your own local gerrit server for AOSP development.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the second step from here: https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading#using-a-local-mirror

You init/sync your mirror over the internet:

```
cd /usr/local/aosp/mirror
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/mirror/manifest --mirror
```

you init/sync your local projects pointing to the mirror as a local file.

```
repo init -u /usr/local/aosp/mirror/platform/manifest.git
```

You are going to have to add platform/manifest.git when you init from the mirror.